# How to remove uploaded file in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am looking to add a remove button to clear selected file.

Can't see any event for removing file

```razor
<InputFile OnChange="@OnInputFileChange">
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To clear the selected file, you can introduce a key attribute to the `InputFile` component. By changing this key value, Blazor will re-render the InputFile as a new component thus clearing the selected file.

```razor
@page "/"

<form @onsubmit="OnSubmit">
    <InputFile @key=@(inputFileId) OnChange="OnInputFileChange"/>
    <br /><br />
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" @onclick="ResetInputFile">Reset</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload Selected File</button>
</form>

@code
{
    private Guid inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
    IBrowserFile selectedFile;

    private void ResetInputFile() 
    {
        // Change id so that blazor re-renders InputFile as new component
        inputFileId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    private void OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        selectedFile = e.GetMultipleFiles()[0];
        // Do stuff
        //this.StateHasChanged();
    }

    private async void OnSubmit()
    {
        if (selectedFile != null)
        {
            // Do stuff
        }
        this.StateHasChanged();
    }
}
```

Output:
[image: Reset InputFile - Blazor]